# linebreaks between results in grep

Tags: bash, grep

I need to occasionally monitor a spider that I have running on my server. I'm testing it to see how many iterations of it are running concurrently and to see if any of them are hanging.

I use this:

```
echo `ps -ewwo args | grep '^[^ ]*curl'`
```

and the output is all in one line. If I change that to

```
echo `ps -ewwo args | grep -n '^[^ ]*curl'`
```

I get the line numbers, but the output is still all in one line. How do I get it to break the results into separate lines?

As a test, I did something like

```
grep "br" /home/user/www/index.php
```

and it found many instances and output them each on a separate line, just like I want I to.

Comment: Why are you using `echo` here at all?

Comment: Michael is correct, your use of echo with no double quotes is the root cause of your whitespace problems.

Comment: At this point, I am pretty much a copy and paste admin, so I found that online. I tried taking it out of the echo and my output was NULL (I think I got that from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=791164 )

Comment: I tried it again. I must have made a mistake when I pulled it out of the echo before. When I just did `ps -ewwo args | grep -n '^[^ ]*curl'` it worked

Comment: Mickael,  If you'll make that an answer, I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: Please see [Process Mananagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't quote the output of a `` `...` `` subshell,
the linebreaks will be replaced with spaces.
If you want the linebreaks then don't use a `` `...` `` subshell,
just run the commands and let them do the outputting by themselves,
without using `echo` at all, for example:

```
ps -ewwo args | grep '^[^ ]*curl'
ps -ewwo args | grep -n '^[^ ]*curl'
```